# Copy specific list to another list

Tags: java

I want to copy specific data from one list to another. It shows

```
ERROR:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at controllers.WebForms.getMenu(WebForms.java:134)
    at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(routes_routing.scala:222)
```

---

```
       List<menu> allMenus = menu.find.all();

       List<menu> selectedMenu=null;
       System.out.println("selected menu:"+selectedMenu);//prints: null
       int count = 0;
       for (models.menu m : allMenus) {
           System.out.println("m:"+m);
           if (m.r_id == r_id) {
               count=1;
               System.out.println("r_id:"+m.r_id+"   "+m.item);
//prints: r_id:1   Noodles
               selectedMenu.add(m);
//throws NULLPointer Exception
               System.out.println("selected menu inside loop:"+selectedMenu);
           }
       }
```

Comment: `List<menu> selectedMenu = new ArrayList<>();`. You have initialise the list before you perform operations on it.

Comment: Thank you Rahul... Thanks alottt... I got the output..

Comment: @RahulSharma You may want to post that as an answer instead.

Comment: I have added it as the answer if you could accept. I see you have added the  answer yourself but you wouldn't be able to accept your own answer. It would be easier for someone to find the answer if there's a green tick against it. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

`List<menu> selectedMenu = new ArrayList<>();`. You have to initialise the list before you perform operations on it.

Answer (score 0):

List selectedMenu = new ArrayList<>();